# Data path "" must NOT have additional properties() after upgrading to angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript

Data path "" must NOT have additional properties()

after upgrading to Angular15 from 13.

below is angular.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Mind20Angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/Boostrap2ToggleCss.css",
              "src/assets/css/BootStrapToggleCSS.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXBodyStyles.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXBootStrapExt.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXDecorationUtils.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXFooterStyles.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXFormUtils.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXGlobalStyles.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXGridStack.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXGridStackExtra.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXHeaderStyles.css",
              "src/assets/css/IGXUIEditor.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css",
              "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "rgbcolor",
              "highcharts",
              "moment",
              "xlsx",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.reduce.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.reverse.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.index-of.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.promise.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.match.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.starts-with.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.includes.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.match.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.ends-with.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.replace.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.trim.js",
              "core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js",
              "raf",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.split.js",
              "jspdf-autotable"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa":{
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging":{
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Mind20Angular:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "Mind20Angular:build:development"
            },
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "Mind20Angular:build:staging"
            },
            "qa": {
              "browserTarget": "Mind20Angular:build:qa"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Mind20Angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Mind",
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "mind20",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration development",
    "qa-start": "ng serve --configuration qa",
    "staging-start": "ng serve --configuration staging",
    "build": "ng build --configuration development",
    "qa-build": "ng build --configuration qa",
    "staging-build": "ng build --configuration staging",
    "prod-build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.8",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^10.0.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^10.3.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.28",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^10.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-http-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-csv": "^0.3.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "simple-ng-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xng-breadcrumb": "^9.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.192",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.60.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.60.0",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

running the below command
`ng build --configuration development --configuration production -- --base-href /Mind/`

Tried removing node modules and ran npm install but getting the same issue